# King Josiah famous last words?

Tags: death, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, quotations, book-of-chronicles

I was told that the tale of king Josiah's death has a few versions. I was told one of Josiah's last words or famous words after he was hit with arrows was in regards to his own error for not listening to the Kohen's advice and allow Neco though Israel.

What did he say exactly? (I remember it was something relating to his being in error, not Hashem.)

My understanding this is the reason there is also a special prayer in Tisha B'Av for King Josiah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Taanis 22b](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=taanis&daf=22b) relates that Yoshiyahu said "צדיק הוא ה׳ כי פיהו מריתי" - HaShem is righteous for I have rebelled against his word. (quote from [Eicha 1:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3201.htm#18))